# The type error does not print the exception statement that I included

Tags: python, exception, typeerror

The purpose here is to catch all the errors when a sequence is tested using checked_f(seq). I tested this program by running checked_f([]), checked_f([1,2,3]) etc. The program catches errors for every test and displays "carefree_f() raised a known exception" except for this test checked_f((1, 2), (2, 3)).It doesn't print this statement "carefree_f() raised a known exception".

```
 def checked_f(seq):
        try:
            return carefree_f(seq)
        except TypeError:
            print('carefree_f() raised a known exception')
            return None
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print('carefree_f() raised a known exception')
            return None
        except IndexError:
            print('enter code here carefree_f() raised a known exception')
            return None
        except AttributeError:
            print('carefree_f() raised a known exception')
            return None
    def carefree_f(seq):
      (u, v) = seq.pop()
      while seq:
        (x, y) = seq.pop()
        u += x
        v += y
      return u / v
```

Comment: If I call `checked_f` with bad input, all I will see is a vague error message that *something* went wrong if it returns `None`. If you can't actually *do* something about an exception, don't catch it at all, or at least re-raise it. `checked_f` should never return `None`; it should either return `u/v`, or it should throw an exception.

Comment: This is for school and the testing manual says that "carefree_f() raised a known exception" should be printed.

Answer (score 1):

> except for this test `checked_f((1, 2), (2, 3))`

In this case, the error is in the caller.

`checked_f()` is defined to accept one argument, but you're passing it *two* arguments: `(1,2), (2,3)`.

Therefore the call is invalid, `checked_f()` is not actually called, and the *calling* code raises an exception.

Comment: But according to the testing manual given to me, this statement should still be printed."carefree_f() raised a known exception"

Comment: So what changes do you think I should  make to get this output ?

Comment: The simple remedy is to remove that specific test case.

Comment: I imagine you are missing a pair of brackets or parentheses. You might mean to pass a list of tuples, like checked_f([(1,2),(2,3)])